# Is 3D optical lattice just a stack of 2D lattices?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics, many-body, cold-atoms

I am confused about the idea of 3D optical lattice. Many papers use 3D optical lattice to study bosons behavior, but is it really a 3D system where atoms interact in all three directions or is it just a stack of independent 2D optical lattices? My confusion comes from a method that suppresses tunneling between lattice sites in 1D optical lattice. Basically, if your lattice is placed vertically (along the gravitational field) then difference in gravitational energy between the sites prevents tunneling.

If 3D lattice is just collection of 2D lattices then theoretical models based on vertical tunneling should be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a 3D lattice allows tunnelling along all three directions. One then makes a 2D lattice (or really a series of 2D lattices) just by turning up the power in one of the lattice lasers to isolate the sheets.

There may be specific configurations in which gravity prevents tunnelling between vertical layers (presumably by creating Bloch oscillations with an amplitude of less than one lattice site), but it is not true in general.